# How to create a JayData model entity with a Knockout ko.computed property?

Tags: knockout.js, jaydata

Using this simple example model:

```
function Person(){
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable();
    self.lastName = ko.observable();
    self.fullName = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.firstName() + ' ' + self.lastName();
    }); 
}
```

How would you implement FullName with JayData?

```
$data.Entity.extend("Person", {
    FirstName: { type: String },
    LastName: { type: String },
    FullName: ???
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it is not supported. Workaround can be made.

Comment: I do not know much about breeze.